# Const int ao invés de número no vetor em C

Tags: c, programação-estruturada

Esse exercício pedia para armazenar 4 notas de 4 alunos e depois fazer a media colocar num vetor e apresentar, pois bem, eu declarei a matriz e ao invés de digitar [4][4] eu coloquei duas variáveis const int valendo 4, e o programa rejeitou, alguém sabe por que aconteceu isso e se estou errado em colocar uma constante ao invés de numero?
o erro que dá é variable-sized object may not be initialized, eu criei a variavel bbimestre pois a Bimestre é constante

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){

const int Bimestre  = 4;
const int Numeroaluno = 4;

float AlunoBimestre [Bimestre][Numeroaluno] = {0};
int media = 0;
float MediaAluno[Bimestre] = {0};

printf("Digite as notas do aluno 1");

  for (int aluno = 0;aluno <Bimestre;aluno++){
        for (int bbimestre = 0; bbimestre < Numeroaluno; bimestre++){
        scanf("%f", &AlunoBimestre[aluno][bbimestre]);
        media = media + AlunoBimestre[aluno][bimestre];
        }
        MediaAluno[aluno] = media / 4;
        media = 0;
        if (aluno!=3)
        printf("Digite as notas do aluno %i \n", aluno + 2);
        }
   for (aluno = 0; aluno <= 4; aluno++){
    printf("A media do aluno %i eh %f",aluno + 1, MediaAluno[aluno]);
    printf("\n");
   }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Dizer `o programa rejeitou` é algo muito vago, poste qual erro o compilador informou. No código que postou existe uma confusão entre `bbimestre` e `bimestre` e creio que uma troca de `Bimestre` com `Numeroaluno` que, neste caso em particular, não causa efeitos colaterais pois as variáveis tem o mesmo valor.

Comment: o erro que dá é variable-sized object may not be initialized, eu criei a variavel bbimestre pois a Bimestre é constante

Comment: Se você declarou seu array com dimensões dinâmicas você não pode inicializa-lo na declaração. Note que `bimestre` é diferente de `Bimestre`, pois C é case sensitive. Veja funcionando em: https://ideone.com/fLGJT3

Comment: ahh, se eu nao coloco nenhum valor no vetor entao isso em da a possibilidade de colocar valor depois usando um laço for por exemplo, mas se eu declarar e colocar valor ao mesmo tempo eu nao posso mais trocar os valores dentro do vetor?

Comment: O problema é o momento em que isso é feito, durante a compilação ou no início da carga do programa. Uma declaração de um array de dimensões dinâmicas não tem suas dimensões conhecidas durante a compilação.

Comment: Note que a atribuição de valores na declaração de uma variável, inclusive arrays, não impede que estes valores seja modificados durante a execução do programa, exceto, obviamente, se a variável tiver sido declarada com `const`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){

const int Bimestre  = 4;
const int Numeroaluno = 4;

float AlunoBimestre [Bimestre][Numeroaluno];
int media = 0;
float MediaAluno[Bimestre];

printf("Digite as notas do aluno 1");
int aluno = 0;

for (int aluno = 0;aluno <Bimestre;aluno++){
    for (int bbimestre = 0; bbimestre < Numeroaluno; bbimestre++){
    scanf("%f", &AlunoBimestre[aluno][bbimestre]);
    media = media + AlunoBimestre[aluno][bbimestre];
    }
    MediaAluno[aluno] = media / 4;
    media = 0;
    if (aluno!=3)
    printf("Digite as notas do aluno %i \n", aluno + 2);
    }
 for (aluno = 0; aluno < 4; aluno++){
   printf("A media do aluno %i eh %f",aluno + 1, MediaAluno[aluno]);
   printf("\n");
}
return 0;
}
```